# getstring() giving null value in jsonparsing

Tags: android, json

I am getting following response from server

```
{"RESPONSE":"ATTENDANCE","STATUS":"SUCCESS","projid":1,"invalid_labours":[]}.
```

i wrote following code of parsing

```
 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(attendanceResponse);
    String response = jsonObj.getString("RESPONSE);
    String status = jsonObj.getString("STATUS);
    String projectID = jsonObj.getString("projid");
    JSONArray invalidLaborId = jsonObj.getJSONArray("invalid_labours");
```

but its giving nullpointer while fetching projid field

Comment: jsonObj.getString("RESPONSE **"** );

Comment: there are different data types in JSON: http://www.json.com/#data-types

Answer (score 5):

Replace

```
String projectID = jsonObj.getString("projid");
```

with

```
int projectID = jsonObj.getInt("projid");
```

---

Also it seems you are missing a double quote...

-------------------------------------------------------------------------\/

```
String response = jsonObj.getString("RESPONSE");
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

`String projectID = jsonObj.getString("projid");`

with

```
int projectID = jsonObj.getInt("projid");
```

Comment: That's not going to compile, getInt returns an int, as the method name suggests...

Comment: @0699 : The answer has been edited. The comment from 2Dee was correct at the time it was posted but not now since the edit.

Comment: Did you replace int projectID = jsonObj.getInt("projid");

Answer (score 0):

projid has an integer value, try the following if you want a String :

```
String projectID = String.valueOf(jsonObj.getInt("projid"));
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are try to get value from `JSONObject` try to use `optXXX()` method

in your case you are `projectID` is int so

```
int projectID = jsonObj.optInt("projid");
```

Difference between `optXXXX()` and `getXXXX()` method

**optInt()**

Get an optional int value associated with a key, or zero if there is no such key or if the value is not a number. If the value is a string, an attempt will be made to evaluate it as a number.

**getInt()**

Get the int value associated with a key.

This method throws: `JSONException` - if the key is not found or if the value cannot be converted to an integer.